# Should I use different WSAOVERLAPPED struct for WSASend and WSARecv?

Tags: windows, sockets, winsock, winsock2

I'm developing a server-client application using WinSock.

Does using the same WSAOVERLAPPED with both WSASend and WSARecv works well? Should I use different WSAOVERLAPPED struct for WSASend and WSARecv?

Comment: Well, if you have multiple I/O requests outstanding then you must use separate structures.  10 outstanding WSARecv() calls need 10 diferent overlapped blocks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using event handle (a member of the `WSAOVERLAPPED` structure) you should definitely use two different structures for sending and receiving.

Comment: If you are using overlapped I/O at all, you MUST use a different overlapped block for each outstanding I/O request.